# How Do You Port Forward on a Motorola SBV5121 Router?

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I've been searching for hours, and apparently this is an obscure model of router or something, because there are no guides on how to port forward this model of router. I can't even find the port forwarding page! I use this IP to connect: 192.168.100.1, and this is what the page looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkKmO.jpg I've tried navigating this place, but all that I see is displays. What do I do to forward a port?

Comment: It's a cable modem not a router. There is no port forwarding on cable modems.

Comment: Might I also have a router, or could I only have Modem?

Comment: **Please read the manual for your device** - http://www.speedguide.net/images/hardware/motorola/sbv5121_ug.pdf, page 33 "The SBV5121 VoIP cable modem supports several multiple user configurations. Along with an optional hub or
**router**, it can serve as an Internet gateway for up to 31 computers.
Not all service providers support multiple user service. For information about multiple user service, contact your
cable provider."